# Heroku deployment successful, but Application has an error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, heroku

I have a small project that I have been working on that can be found [here](https://github.com/DavidReider/MagicEdenFloorTrack).
The project was originally vanilla HTML, CSS and JavaScript, but I have been working on converting it to React in a feature branch.

I tried to deploy the branch to Heroku, which appears to be successful, however when I try to visit the application, it gives me an Application error. When I check the logs, it is outputting like so

> 2022-01-19T02:45:57.270692+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
> 2022-01-19T02:45:57.270731+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the meapi@1.0.0 start script.
> 2022-01-19T02:45:57.270767+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
> 2022-01-19T02:45:57.275755+00:00 app[web.1]:
> 2022-01-19T02:45:57.275856+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> 2022-01-19T02:45:57.275902+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2022-01-19T02_45_57_271Z-debug.log
> 2022-01-19T02:45:57.405061+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
> 2022-01-19T02:45:57.506577+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
> 2022-01-19T02:45:58.536667+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=magicedenfloortracker.herokuapp.com request_id=92ecc3ce-83c0-497a-8453-06a7abf9f9f1 fwd="152.208.11.3" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
> 2022-01-19T02:45:58.762210+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=magicedenfloortracker.herokuapp.com request_id=b1d68b37-1cbb-4245-825b-0ebe77fa6f90 fwd="152.208.11.3" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

I'm not quite sure what to make of these error logs though. Since the path to the create-react-app folder isn't standard, I tried to create a Procfile and set `web: cd .\floor-track\ && npm start` thinking that it might cd into the folder then run npm start first, but I am not sure that is working as I expected.

Any tips on resolving this issue?

Additionally, outside of the react folder, I have a file 'api.js' that I would like to run hourly (uses node cron) but I am not sure how to run this file in the background on heroku. Is this possible as well?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you use Create React App? If not, what specifically `npm start` does?

Comment: @tymzap from the root of the github repository, `npm start` is set to run `node api.js`; however, inside of the create-react-app folder, `npm start` is set to run `react-scripts start`. You can see the project [here](https://github.com/DavidReider/MagicEdenFloorTrack/tree/feat-react-revamp)

Comment: `error code=H10` may suggest that you don't use `PORT` variable provided by Heroku to start the app

Comment: Hi @tymzap - do I need to include that? I don't have that anywhere I don't believe. Where would it go?